# What is the difference between .zip() vs Observable.zip() (rxjs ^5.5.6)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm new to rxjs and use `"rxjs": "^5.5.6"` in Angular 5 project. 
I have the issue with importing zip from different locations.

this code works fine:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
...
Observable.zip(
    this.loadTexture('1.png'),
    this.loadTexture('2.jpg'),
    this.loadTexture('3.jpg'),
    (t1, t2, t3) => ({ fairCloudsTexture: t1, noCloudsTexture: t2, elevBumpTexture: t3 })
).subscribe((textures) => {
    this.fairCloudsTexture = textures.fairCloudsTexture;
    this.noCloudsTexture = textures.noCloudsTexture;
    this.elevBumpTexture = textures.elevBumpTexture;
    this.initThreeJS();
});
```

but when I use this import it doesnt work:

```
import { zip } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
zip(
    this.loadTexture('1.png'),
    this.loadTexture('2.jpg'),
    this.loadTexture('3.jpg'),
    (t1, t2, t3) => ({ fairCloudsTexture: t1, noCloudsTexture: t2, elevBumpTexture: t3 })
).subscribe((textures) => {
    this.fairCloudsTexture = textures.fairCloudsTexture;
    this.noCloudsTexture = textures.noCloudsTexture;
    this.elevBumpTexture = textures.elevBumpTexture;
    this.initThreeJS();
});
```

What is the difference between this two `zip` methods? Why am I getting this error? 
`Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<{ fairCloudsTexture: {}; noCloudsTexture: {}; elevBumpTexture: {}; }>>'.ts(2339)`

Comment: There's `zip`  from `'rxjs/operators'` that is an operator used inside rx chains. Then there's `zip` from `'rxjs'` which is so-called Observable creation method that return an Observable.

Comment: @martin how do I google this? I see now in their docs they have zip in `API / rxjs/operators` and in `API / rxjs/index`

Comment: yeah, it's confusing. That's why it'll be renamed in future RxJS releases https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3927